# Cant read .bak files

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to read .bak files that are the backup files of my ms sql database.Now I am wodering how to read these files using Sql Mngmnt studio. Please help me out .Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restore the .BAK file to a temporary database using SQL Management Studio and read them!

Some pointers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you can [restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) the `.bak` file.there you get all the datas