# Why cannot I open .bak files with SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cant read .bak files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499450/cant-read-bak-files)

Title pretty much says it. I am trying to open up a `.bak` file that my employer gave me but yet I cannot open them with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2.

It says to download something but I cannot find anything online and doesn't tell me what to download...

Comment: It just says to download 'something'?  Can you tell us the specific error message?  Also, what version of SQL Server was the .bak file created with?

Comment: What format are the .bak files supposed to be? How are you trying to open them? What is the exact error message?

Comment: "It says to download something but I cannot find anything online and doesn't tell me what to download" - can you show us this message precisely? Either type it out exactly as-is or post a screenshot. Thanks! And are you sure your employer is using SQL Server and isn't using SQL Server 2012? The backups aren't always backward compatible.

Comment: `.bak` files are **backup*8 files. They have to be restored first. Read the documentation in SQL Server Books Online (in the Start Menu, type `SQL Server Books` in the search box, or search MSDN for `SQL Server RESTORE`).

Comment: What does "open" a .bak file mean? A .bak file is usually a backup file, i.e. a binary file containing a database backup. You `RESTORE` it to a running SQL Server instance and then connect to the instance to use it. Or when you said "open" did you mean "restore"?

Comment: I had the same problem, essentially you try to load a SQL backup in ssms, and instead of loading it, it decides it cannot identify the file, even though it's patently obvious what should be done with the file and it knows what application to open it with because the application is running (duh!). You will then get a windows popup prompting you to choose the application to open with. If that's not stupid enough, when you select ssms as an application to open bak files, it spawns off a new instance of ssms and it still fails anyway!

Answer (score 4):

Typically the `.bak` extension indicates a backup file that you can restore to an existing or new database.

In SSMS you can right-click an existing database then select Tasks > Restore > Database...

Comment: This is the correct answer, although it seems you can open a backup file, in practice you can't. You can only "restore" a backup.